# nginx (+ php-fpm) sometimes returns http code = 499

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a `script.php` that is called via curl and runs for about 40 minutes.

Sometimes the script just stops in the middle.

In nginx `access.log` script call completes with strange http code `499`.
There are no errors in php-fpm logs.

In php config `max_execution_time = 9000`

I implied that the problem may be in the timeout and set in the configuration nginx with a large margin `fastcgi_read_timeout = 2h;` but the problem is not solved.

Which way to dig, since there are no errors in the logs.

Comment: This is an Nginx specific status code that means **client has closed connection** before the server answered the request.

Comment: @RichardSmith In this case, the client is the one who calls script.php - right? Cron calls script.php via curl request - no errors when working through Apache, but on Nginx periodically breaks with code 499. Consequently, something is wrong in the configuration of Nginx, but I have read the documentation several times, corrected seemingly the right variables, but the problem does not go away.

Comment: Please see this solution... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724098/1004587

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu Thanks for the tip, unfortunately, I edited the correct config))